# AJAXifying content and pagination problems

Tags: 7, views, ajax, paging

I am using the [Ajax links API](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api) module that allows to load a node inside a `<div>` tag by using `<a class="ajax-link" href="node/add/page" rel="#content">Add page</a>`.

However, I have a problem: If I use a pager, and I click on the link to see another page, I will be redirected to that page, instead of loading it inside the `<div>` tag.

I solved partially by using the [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module, but if I have several `<div>` tags, the module doesn't load the correct view in the correct `<div>`.

It seems I cannot use the pagination because the URL is not re-written to accommodate to the container, and it is not scrolling because this limitation.

Is there some way of creating simple AJAX calls loading content in different `<div>` tags on the same page, and with pagination (or load more button, infinite scrolling, etc.)?

Comment: You are trying to do this using Views Module...right?

Comment: Right, with module Views.

Comment: Please check if you have Ajax: Yes in your View.

Comment: Yes, I have Ajax: Yes checked, and the URL link displays the &ajax=1 parameter. However, as the class "ajax-link" is not used not rewritten in the pager, when clicking on Next page, it directs the browser to another page, instead of loading the content with Ajax.

Comment: Looks like you are not the only with "Ajax not working on Ajax Loaded Content". Found below link which could be helpful for you. https://www.drupal.org/node/1877446 To be honest i haven't tried to replicate your problem, but i think you should find solution in patch #15, as stated in comments by quite a few people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below solution with views pager ajax enable.

jQuery 1.7+ Version

```
function runthiscode() {
  $(".pager a").each(function(){
    $(".pager a").addClass("ajax-link");
    $(".pager a").attr('rel', '#content')
  });
}

$(document ).ready(function() {
  runthiscode();
});

$(document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  runthiscode();
});
```

Comment: While I solved the problem by uninstalling modules, deleting cache, and low-level database entries, this solution will work in other general instances, mainly on Nested Views and the like, so IMHO it deservs the 50 points bounty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem is similar to [Ajax pager does not work as expected for nested views](https://www.drupal.org/node/1877446), I had this problem before and  [patch #15](https://www.drupal.org/node/1877446#comment-8372423) help me to resolve.

take a look  and try that if it not work tell me I suggest you another solution

Comment: I have never used pathcing nor Drush. I am not sure why this problem is not solved in the main code.

Comment: @Cesar what is your operation system? mac? windows? linux?
what is your IDE ?

Comment: Windows XP, Aptana and FTP, with XAMPP for testing.

Comment: @Cesar  I *Suggest*  learn how to patch, really it's good for you .
very easy way to apply patch( this is traditional and not recommend method ) is manually patching : "
open `views/js/ajax_view.js` file, and also open 
www.drupal.org/files/issues/1877446-15-views-ajax-pager-closest-parent_1.patch ,  remove each line in `ajax_view.js` when you see has **-** in *patch* and also add lines to `ajax_view.js`  that has *+* mark."
Also read this about  "patch" for Windows XP
 www.drupal.org/node/23844
Read this one too stackoverflow.com/questions/517257/how-do-i-apply-a-diff-patch-on-windows

Comment: I will try to learn how to patch someday in the future. Meanwhile, I will follow your by-hand avcisee, -- = remove line, ++ = add line, keeping a save copy. Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Applying a patch is literally one command... learn it. Some patches are so large you are bound to miss a change by manually copy pasting over things.

Comment: @Cesar you're welcome, inform me fro the result and if you need help feel free, we are here to help other drupalists

Comment: Now after deleting all, and creating the View from scratch, if I activate Use Ajax in the View, it will work perfectly, as it should have from the beginning. No need of patch, which may be ok for nested views. I will try to have a nested view and replicate the results, I think that there were some conflicts among modules and now that I cleaned it completely, the problem does not manifest itself.

Comment: @Cesar congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with below jquery solution.

jQuery 1.7+ Version

```
function runthiscode() {
  $(".pager a").each(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $('.pager a').on('click', function(event){
      $("#content").load(a_href+" #content");
    });
  });
}

$(document ).ready(function() {
  runthiscode();
});

$(document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  runthiscode();
});
```